# Python script to build the docker image throwing "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: python, docker

I'm writing below script which will build docker image and then push it to ECR.
Here, in this snippet I'm posting the error while building the image.  This is in Window OS local machine and python version is 3.8.0

I have below folderstructure:

```
/home:
-->ECR
-->buildImage.py
Dockerfile
```

The script `/home/ECR/buildImage.py` looks like this:

```
import docker
docker_api = docker.APIClient()

    dockerfile_path = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    print("Docker file location: " + dockerfile_path)
    if os.path.isfile(dockerfile_path + "\\Dockerfile"):
        print("File exists")
    else:
        print("File does not exist...")

docker_api.build(path=dockerfile_path, tag=local_tag, rm=True, dockerfile=".\\Dockerfile")
```

This above throws me error:

```
pywintypes.error: (2, 'WaitNamedPipe', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

and with this one,

```
docker_api.build(path='dockerfile_path', tag=local_tag, rm=True, dockerfile=".\\Dockerfile")
```

this throws me

```
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
```

How can I fix this? Is it necessary that on your local machine which in my case in Window Docker should be available? Docker is not installed but docker python package version `4.1.0` is installed.

```
print(docker.__version__)
>> 4.1.0
```

Comment: You need to have docker installed locally as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the Docker Engine installed as well. This is a Python API for the Docker Engine, so it is just using the source code from your local Docker through a python interface. Furthermore, your version of API needs to match your Docker engine SDK.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/):

**Versioned API and SDK**

---

The version of the Docker Engine API you should use depends upon the version of your Docker daemon and Docker client.

A given version of the Docker Engine SDK supports a specific version of the Docker Engine API, as well as all earlier versions. If breaking changes occur, they are documented prominently.

Daemon and client API mismatches

- The Docker daemon and client do not necessarily need to be the same version at all times. However, keep the following in mind.
- If the daemon is newer than the client, the client does not know about new features or deprecated API endpoints in the daemon.
- If the client is newer than the daemon, the client can request API endpoints that the daemon does not know about."

Comment: thanks got it. Since this my window machine and it will be pain. So I moved to machine where docker engine is installed. How can I make sure my python api  is compatible with docker engine? python docker version is `4.1.0` while linux2 machine both engine and client version is `1.39` and on `DOcker 18.09.9-ce`. Now if I run the script it shows me `  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

Comment: Look at the doc link I posted. There is a table on the bottom which shows which api is compatible with which docker. You can pip install a specified version of the api consistent with your docker version.

Comment: thanks again. I have gone thru the links and everything is compatible. but I think, It's working now, it's just the way I was referring the location is not right. But now im able to build it. If anyone wants reference https://pypi.org/project/docker/ is great help.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved. If this was helpful consider giving it an upvote, and if it answered your question click the green check mark to indicate that for future visitors to the question.